# 'struct std::pair<int, int>' has no member named 'serialize'

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to integrate serialization into my code. However, I get the a 'has no member named' error. The book I'm reading says that std::pair doesn't need a header file to include and there does not exist  . How to fix this error?
My code look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
//ofstream/ifstream
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
//stringstream
#include <sstream>
//
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>  
#include <boost/serialization/bitset.hpp>   
//#include <boost/serialization/

//BOOST_BINARY
#include <boost/utility/binary.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    complex<double> c(1,0); 
    bitset<3> b(BOOST_BINARY(101)); 
    pair<int,int> p(1,2);   
    string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa<<c<<b<<p;    
    {
        complex<double> c;
        bitset<3> b;
        pair<int,int> p;
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        ia>>c>>b>>p;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::pair` is defined in `<utility>`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>` to enable `std::pair` serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Why should `std::pair` provide a `serialize` function? The standard never says that. It is also incorrect to say it does not need a header file: it requires <utility> really. It is, however, probably already included by another header file you use.

You can provide your own `serialize` function. Boost already provides examples. In your case, you need to add the following code before `main`.

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template <class Archive, typename T1, typename T2>
void serialize(Archive& ar, std::pair<T1, T2>& pr, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & pr.first;
    ar & pr.second;
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

By the way, I do not see the need of using `string s` in your code. You can remove that line and just use:

```
std::stringstream ss;
```

Comment: The pair serialization code is in `<boost/serialization/utility.hpp>`, no need to write your own.